# How can I make this CSS transition less shaky in Firefox?

Tags: css, css-transforms

Please test the following fiddle in Safari or Chrome as well as Firefox. You will notice that the animation is smooth in Safari, even after the mouse is no longer hovering over the div (when the div has moved past the mouse). In Firefox, however, once the div moves to where the mouse is no longer touching, it begins to move back to its original position, thus causing an unsightly shake. Can I use JavaScript to resolve this issue?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aqfvn/)

```
#object01 {
   position:relative;
   margin-top:10em;
   width:300px;
   height:300px;
   background-color:red;
   border:2px solid black;
   transform:rotate(5deg);
   -webkit-transform:rotate(5deg);
   -moz-transform:rotate(5deg);
   -o-transform:rotate(5deg);
   -ms-transform:rotate(5deg);
   z-index:1000;
   transition:all 1s ease;
   -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
   -ms-transition:all 1s ease;
   -moz-transition:all 1s ease;
   -o-transition:all 1s ease;
   top:0;
}

#object01:hover {
   transform:rotate(0deg);
   -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
   -moz-transform:rotatate(0deg);
   -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
   -ms-transform:rotate(0deg);
   top:-250px;
}
```

Comment: Looks like Safari's behavior is wrong here, not Firefox' behavior.

Comment: Regardless, is there any way to make this transform behave like Safari in Firefox?

Comment: I think it might be better if you wrapped the object in a larger div giving it more hover area. That way if the user does hover just outside the object moving up won't break the hover pseudoclass.

Comment: @johnP Thanks for the suggestion! I'm having a hard time visualizing it though. So would it be the larger div's hover class that would have top:-250px?

Comment: @StephenWidom I think something like this would do the trick `#parent:hover #object01 {/* css */}` So as long as the mouse is within the larger boundary, the animation will happen and the box will move. Since the bounding box remains static the whole time, you shouldn't have to deal with any weirdness.

Comment: another thing to try: i had shaky transformations in firefox with percentile width elements. Adding a `transform-origin` property removed any shakiness in firefox in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid need to change the markup, you can add a pseudo-element and animate in in the opposite direction, so it will 'hold the active area' when the main element is moved:

```
#object01:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease;
    -o-transition:all 1s ease;
    transition:all 1s ease;
}

#object01:hover:after {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(250px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(250px);
    -o-transform: translateY(250px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(250px));    
    transform: translateY(250px);
}
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aqfvn/6/))

Also, there are several observations that animation has better performance and goes smoother if animating `transform: translate(...)` than if animating `top`/`left`: [1](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/), [2](http://blog.tumult.com/2013/02/28/transform-translate-vs-top-left/). And it's better if the unprefixed property goes after the prefixed ones (because if the browser supports both prefixed and unprefixed syntax, there are more chances for the prefixed implementation to be buggy than for the unprefixed one). And there is no need to specify `-ms-transition` since IE9 doesn't understand it, and all shipped versions of IE10 support the unprefixed syntax.